# Help identifying pins in EVQV9C00116E rotary encoder

Tags: datasheet, pins, encoder, rotary

[image]

I'm trying to make a button box for a sim racing rig and need a few rotary encoders for menu browsing. I plan to connect it to an arduino but I can't seem to figure out how to wire things up. I have found the datasheet for the encoder, but can't figure out what pin does what.

How do I connect and use the EVQV9C00116E rotary encoder with an arudino?

Comment: Wow, I completely missed those labels. Thank you so much. I believe that is exactly what I need to know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pins are shown in this diagram:

[image]

The first and second pins are shown here (the first diagram is from the bottom up, the second from the top down):

[image: ed]

Your confusion may stem from the fact, that a lot of rotary encoders around foster quadrature outputs. This encoder puts out a gray code instead. I.e. the four output pins are the bits of a series of numbers where only one bit is changing between two positions. This means, this encoder provides an absolute position but can be used as a relative encoder as well. You can use three XOR-gates to generate an single interrupt for rotation detection.

Connect the VCC of the arudino to the pin 5 of the roatary encoder, and connect pins 1-4 to the arudino (or just one of the pins if you only need to detect one rotation). You could use [interrupts to toggle code](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/using-interrupts-on-arduino/) whenever it detects a rising or falling edge